# Why is $u(z) = \frac {z^{1-p}}{1-p}$ taken as $log(z)$ when $p=1$?

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, economics, utility

We want our function $u(z)$ to have constant $-\frac{zu''(z)}{u'(z)}$.

Let $u(z) = \frac {z^{1-p}}{1-p}$ when $p$ is not 1, and
$u(z) = log(z)$ when $p=1$.

Why do we take it as $log(z)$? How does this keep the $-\frac{zu''(z)}{u'(z)}$ constant?

Comment: You can take anything as anything anywhere, but perhaps the context would help. Where do you see this? What is the limit as $z\to0$ of $u(z)$?

Comment: I guess it's more like the limit of $u(z; p)$ as $p \to 1$

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Edited for clarity.

Comment: $u(z)=\log(z)$ implies $-\frac{zu''(z)}{u'(z)}=1$, so the extension is correct in this context

Comment: Did you try taking the first and second derivatives of $u(z)=\log(z)$, which I presume stands for the natural logarithm, and plugging them into this expression $-\frac{zu''(z)}{u'(z)}$? This is a straightforward calculation which will address the "Why is it constant?" question. But "Why take this function?" is a whole different question, impossible to answer without knowing the context.

Comment: Something that's easy to get confused about is that the "right" antiderivative in the power rule to be able to pass through the case involving the logarithm in a "pretty" way is $\int_1^x y^p dy = \frac{y^{p+1}-1}{p+1}$. That $-1$ in the numerator is needed to ensure that as $p \to -1$, you are differentiating rather than dividing a quantity that isn't going to zero by a quantity that is going to zero.

Comment: Typo, it should be $\frac{x^{p+1}-1}{p+1}$ in my previous comment (not $y$ in the numerator).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you run into this impasse when you try to find an antiderivative for $x^{-1}$  (because using the power rule, we get stuck with $\dfrac{x^0}0$, which doesn't work).  Thus one (cleverly)  defines and studies $\ln x:=\int^x_1\dfrac1t\operatorname{dt}$.

Then it turns out that this function is the inverse of $e^x$.

Answer (score 4):

You have $$ \lim_{p\rightarrow 1}\Big(\frac{z^{1-p}}{1-p}-\frac{1}{1-p}\Big) = \lim_{p\rightarrow 1}\Big(\frac{e^{(1-p)\ln z} -1}{1-p}\Big) = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{e^{x\ln z} -1}{x} =\ln z$$